# Corrupt sd card is seen by gnome-disks, but can't format

Tags: filesystems, storage, gparted, sd-card, removable-storage

Somehow I can see the sd-card in gnome-disks as /dev/sda, but it won't show up in gparted. In gnome-disks it shows as a mass storage device with no media, or size, and it won't allow me to edit anything.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: The card has probably failed. Check the `dmesg` output: if it shows I/O error messages when you're trying to access the card, either the card or the reader has failed.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.